# how to use display flex instead of float left and float right

Tags: css, flexbox

How to use display `flex` instead of `float: left` and `float: right`?

**See below image**

[image]

I tried like this:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

a {
  text-underline: none;
}

.bg {
  background: #eee;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  background: #af2c2c;
}

.logo h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif
}

.menu_hang {
  background-position: -70px -92px;
  background-image: url(https://static.toiimg.com/photo/52121907.cms);
  background-size: 200px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 24px;
  opacity: .8;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="bg">
      <header>
        <div class="header">
          <div>
            <i class="menu_hang"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="logo">
            <h2>HIM</h2>
          </div>
          <div>
            <a href="">share</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

here is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/Jlx5tzSB3CKQRVGrFSfh?p=preview

After using `display flex` . i am facing two issue

1. Menu is hide .
2. share `anchor tag` is showing on top

Comment: In the plnkr I can see the logo.. About the share - [`align-items`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-items.asp). Please read the whole `flex` tutorial in your favorite blog (such as [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)) I'm sure it will answer your future questions.

Comment: i am saying `menu button` `three dots`

Comment: The `i` tag's parent has no `width` due `i` is an inline element. Turn it to `display: block` and you will see the icon.

Comment: wait checking ..will update you soon

Comment: thanks it works ..I used `inline-block` .now still having issue `menu and logo` on `left` and `share` on right ..can we achieve  without using float left and right https://plnkr.co/edit/Jlx5tzSB3CKQRVGrFSfh?p=preview

Comment: Do you mean that you want the `share` button to be in the right? If so, PLEASE, read the tutorial I sent. You have all the answers there..

Comment: yes ..I am reading the tutorial ..

Comment: still not get anwser please help here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The logo is invisible because its parent has no width. It does have  but it's an inline element so we need to make it block by `display: block` (or `inline-block`).
2. To center an item inside `flex` container, you can use `align-items: center;`.
3. To move the `share` link to the right we need to, basically, tell the browser that we want that the `.logo` container will take the whole space. We can do this by `flex-grow: 1`. That means that the "important" element is `.logo` and it will take the space.

All together:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.bg {
  background: #eee;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #af2c2c;
  
}

.logo {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.logo h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif
}

.menu_hang {
  display: block;
  background-position: -70px -92px;
  background-image: url(https://static.toiimg.com/photo/52121907.cms);
  background-size: 200px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 24px;
  opacity: .8;
}

.share-container {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="bg">
    <header>
      <div class="header">
        <div>
          <i class="menu_hang"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="logo">
          <h2>HIM</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="share-container">
          <a href="">share</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/5SYSWCHzHAe3ED5K?p=info&preview

BTW: there is no `text-underline` css property. You meant probably to `text-decoration: none`.

Comment: thanks for answer it almost correct ...I want to know something like if I want to give some margin from right to `share` button how I can do that ..I tried to give position relative and right :20.but not work

Comment: `padding` works for me https://plnkr.co/edit/Jlx5tzSB3CKQRVGrFSfh?p=preview

Comment: but still there is one `last` issue look at `logo` and `menu` both are not is same `line` .logo is just few pixel `below` can I solve this .can I add margin between two field

Comment: I just updated my answer. If you want to align the logo to the menu, you need to set `display: block` to the `i`. And the margin works for me..