# How to align 3 boxes in the center

Tags: html, css

I've done it before, but for some reason I can't figure it out now no matter what I try. Trying to align these 3 boxes in the center, in a row. They are lined up in a row, but I can't get them to center.

```css
.box{
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin: 5em;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    background: skyblue;
}
.box1{
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin: 5em;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    background: red;

}
.box2{
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin: 5em;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    background: orange

 }
```

```html
<div class="contact">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box1"></div>
        <div class="box2"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all `float:left` and add this CSS

```
 .box,.box1, .box2 {
   display: inline-block;
 }
 .contact {
   text-align: center;
 }
```

This should work

```css
.box{
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin: 2em;
    
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background: skyblue;
}
.box1{
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin: 2em;

    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background: red;

}
.box2{
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin: 2em;

    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background: orange

 }
 .box,.box1, .box2 {
   display: inline-block;
 }
 .contact {
   text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<div class="contact">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box1"></div>
        <div class="box2"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your contact div a `width` and `margin: auto;`:

```
.contact {
width: 600px; // should be 3 * 180 + 2 * 5em 
margin: auto;
}
```

Alternatively you can use [flex-box instead of floats](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49965479/3163075).

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to worry about setting a `width`, you can simply set `display: inline-block` on the container (`.contact`), and `text-align: center` on the container's parent (in this case, `body`).

This can be seen in the following (run the code snippet, then view it full page):

```css
.box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin: 5em;
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  background: skyblue;
}

.box1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin: 5em;
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  background: red;
}

.box2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin: 5em;
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  background: orange
}

.contact {
  display: inline-block;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set display attribute to inline-flex for contact class
:

```
.contact{
   display: inline-flex;
 }
```

Below is the snippet example

```css
.box{
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin: 5em;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    background: skyblue;
}
.box1{
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin: 5em;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    background: red;

}
.box2{
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin: 5em;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    background: orange

 }
 .contact{
   display: inline-flex;
 }
```

```html
<div class="contact">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box1"></div>
        <div class="box2"></div>
 </div>
```

This is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vikasguptaa9/7z9sryea/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use display: flex css properties as below. This should be cross-browser compatible as well. This ensures the boxes are centered vertically and horizontally.

```css
.contact {
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-align-items: center;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -moz-justify-content: center;
  -ms-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.box,
.box1,
.box2 {
margin: 0 auto;
margin: 5em;
width: 180px;
height: 180px;
}
.box{
background: skyblue;
}
.box1{
background: red;
}

.box2{
background: orange
 }
```

```html
    <div class="contact">
            <div class="box"></div>
            <div class="box1"></div>
            <div class="box2"></div>
     </div>
```